# Can infinitives be subjects?

Tags: infinitive, subject

Infinitives are often used as direct objects:

> Mi ŝatas *danci*. ( ≈ Mi ŝatas dancadon.)

I wonder if an infinitive could be used as a subject, too?
Would it be correct to say:

> Danci plaĉas al mi.

or even

> Danci plibonigas vian sanon.

Comment: Just to clarify: I’m thinking about infinitives as subjects in main phrases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is no problem with using an infinitive as a subject and I believe it’s not that uncommon. Here is an example from Zamenhof’s translation of the old testament:

> Kaj krom tio, mia filo, akceptu mian instruon, ke se oni volus verki multajn librojn, ne estus fino, kaj multe **legi lacigas** la korpon.

And another example from his translation of Hamlet using *plaĉi*:

> Se **plaĉos** al vi **doni** al mi prudentan respondon, tiam mi plenumos la ordonon de via patrino

[PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/i-verboj/subjekto.html) has a section about this with several other examples.